# Access Slick fields via Database column name

Tags: json, scala, akka, slick, akka-http

I have the following:

```
case class Supplier(id: Long, name: String, desc: String, sales: Int)

class SuppliersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Supplier](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
  def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def desc = column[String]("desc")
  def sales = column[Int]("sales")
  def * = (id, name, desc, sales) <> (Supplier.tupled, Supplier.unapply)
}
```

I need to create a rest interface for CRUD operation, and I need to support operations (update, filter, sort...) done on columns (can be multiple columns per request). Data are in JSON,  where JSON keys are column names.

Sample Request: Update name and sales of supplier 2

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{
  "name": "newSupplierName",
  "sales" : 100
}' localhost:8080/supplier/2
```

How do I tell slick which field(s) to update by just knowing the column names from the JSON request?

My initial plan is to generate plain sql queries from the JSON payload:

Rest Routes:

```
private val supplierUpdateRoute = path("supplier" / IntNumber) { (supId) =>
  put {
    entity(as[String]) { supplierToUpdate => 
      import spray.json._

      val jsonAst = supplierToUpdate.parseJson
      val jsonMap = jsonAst.asJsObject.fields

      onComplete((modules.suppliersDal.update(jsonMap, supId))) {
      // ignoring the number of insertedEntities because in this case it should always be one, you might check this in other cases
      case Success(insertedEntities) => complete(Created)
      case Failure(ex) => complete(InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

DAL Class:

```
def update(jsonMap : Map[String, JsValue], id: Long): Future[Unit] = {

  val tableName = tableQ.baseTableRow.tableName
  //val columns = tableQ.baseTableRow.create_*.map(_.name).toSeq

  val listQuery = jsonMap.foldLeft[List[String]](Nil)((acc, head) => acc :+ s"${head._1} = ${head._2}") 
  val fieldsToUpdate = listQuery.mkString(", ")
  val baseQuery = sqlu"update #${tableName} set #$fieldsToUpdate where id = #$id"


  db.run(DBIO.seq(baseQuery))
}
```

I'm getting some column not found error when columnName defined in SuppliersTable class is in lowercase

ServerLog:

```
1: StreamingInvokerAction$HeadAction [update SUPPLIERS set name = "newSupplierName", sales = 100 where id = 2]
2: success ()
```

ConsoleLog:

```
An error occurred: Column "NAME" not found; SQL statement:
update SUPPLIERS set name = "newSupplierName", sales = 100 where id = 2
```

If I set the column names to all CAPS, I'm getting

```
An error occurred: Column "newSupplierName" not found; SQL statement:
update SUPPLIERS set name = "newSupplierName", sales = 1000 where id = 2
```

I don't know if it's a good idea to create plain sql queries from JSON.  Can you suggest a better way to do this? I also need my api to work even if the tables are altered in the future (add/remove new columns...)

Template used is from Lightbend - [link](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/akka-http-rest)

**EDIT:**

Seems like slick recognise string encapsulated at "" as column name,

Did a workaround to treat json string values as string literals instead of column name by replacing '\"' with '\'':

```
val listQuery = jsonMap.foldLeft[List[String]](Nil)((acc, head) => acc :+ s"${head._1} = ${head._2}") 

val fieldsToUpdate = listQuery.mkString(", ").replace('\"', '\'')
```

Still open for suggestions as I am still not confident with my solution

Comment: You really, really don't want to be creating SQL strings from JSON payloads. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) for why.

Comment: Do you know other way to do it? I still do not have other idea how to do it, I can't create functions for each operation ( updateSupplierName, updateSupplierDesc, updateSupplierNameAndDesc, ...) as it will be a horror maintaining such

Comment: The standard REST-like way is to have `POST` or `PUT` handlers which accept JSON-formatted objects, and simply overwrite (or insert) all of the fields in the database. It means sending more data over the wire, but it's very simple to implement.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand clearly, What if I need to overwrite some of the fields only, would I need to create several JSON-formatted objects (UpdateSupplierNameJson, UpdateSupplierDescJson, UpdateSupplierNameAndDescJson, ...)? Would it be possible to have only one JSON-formatted object per Slick Object wherein only specified fields in the request will be updated

Comment: If you're going for least-code-written, the easiest way is to send the entire object with each request, and update all of the fields in the database each time. Some of the fields won't change, but that should be harmless.

Comment: I don't know if I can use entire object with each request as it would not be friendly to the users of api if they are to include all the fields of the object especially when updating only few fields, right now they are just required to include ID and the fields to update. It might also clear some database columns when user forgot to include some fields on their json request

Comment: Yes, that's the trade-off. A happy medium might be to create a version of `Supplier` with all-optional fields for sending over REST calls, and update only those that are set. You can prevent accidental updates that way, although it makes your database code more complicated.